# Probability of "no bin containing more than some number of balls" when randomly toss nlgn balls into n bins?

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

I am asked:

> Randomly tossing $nlg(n)$ balls into $n$ bins, find $C$ such that $\text{Pr}(\text{No bins containing more than } Clg(n) \text{ balls}) \ge 1-\frac{1}{n}$.

I'm thinking that using Markov's Inequality, the probability of one bin having more than $Clg(n)$ balls is smaller than $\frac{1}{C}$. *If all bins are independent*, then

$$(1-\frac{1}{C})^n\ge1-\frac{1}{n}$$

would give the result, but I am not sure if bins are independent of each other.  I am wondering if there're any alternatives to finding $C$.

Comment: Is there a typo? Please clarify what "$lgn$" refers to.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin sorry I meant "$lg(n)$". Edited.

Comment: So it's natural logarithm? Anyway, there's another one in `Randomly tossing...`

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin yes.